# How to run PowerShell script in a different process and pass arguments to it?

Tags: windows, powershell, process

Let's say I have a script:

```
write-host "Message.Status: Test Message Status";
```

I managed to run it in a separate process by doing:

```
powershell.exe -Command
{ write-host "Message.Status: Test Message Status"; }
```

The problem is I want to pass parameters to the script so that I can achieve something like this:

```
write-host "I am in main process"
powershell.exe -Command -ArgumentList "I","am","here"
{
    write-host "I am in another process"
    write-host "Message.Status: $($one) $($two) $($three)";
}
```

However `-ArgumentList` doesn't work here

I get:

```
powershell.exe : -ArgumentList : The term '-ArgumentList' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
```

I need to run some part of PowerShell script file in a different process and I cannot use another file due to the fact that PowerShell script is uploaded to external system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-Command` parameter is expecting a `scriptblock` in which you can define your parameters using a `Param()` block. Then use the `-args` parameter to pass in the arguments. Your only mistake was to put the `-args` after `-command` *before* you defined the scriptblock.

So this is how it works:

```
write-host "I am in main process $($pid)"
powershell.exe -Command {
    Param(
        $one,
        $two,
        $three
    )
    write-host "I am in process $($pid)"
    write-host "Message.Status: $($one) $($two) $($three)";
} -args "I", "am", "here" | Out-Null
```

**Output:**

```
I am in main process 17900
I am in process 10284
Message.Status: I am here
```

Comment: I've run your code in PowerShell ISE and I got the script block called twice

`PS C:\Users\lixonn> write-host "I am in main process $($pid)"
powershell.exe -Command {
    Param(
        $one,
        $two,
        $three
    )
    write-host "I am in process $($pid)"
    write-host "Message.Status: $($one) $($two) $($three)";
} -args "I", "am", "here"
I am in main process 13444
I am in process 2364


Message.Status: I am here


I am in process 2364
Message.Status: I am here`

Comment: @lixonn The code will be called only once, but you are retrieving the output twice. You can verify that if you add `GUID: $([Guid]::NewGuid())` to each `Write-Host` output. Then you will see that both blocks have the same GUID. However, to fix the output, just pipe the execution to `Out-Null`. I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: "The code will be called only once, but you are retrieving the output twice."   It's true but why is that?

Comment: @lixonn Thats a good question. It seems like ISE always does that, a tiny example is `powershell.exe -command { Write-Host "hello"}`. Whereas the powershell command line seems not to. Unfortunately I don't have an explanation for that, only the workaround with the `Out-Null` pipe. Thanks for accepting the answer.

Comment: Your solution does what I wanted to achieve. This workaround is also acceptable. Thanks for explanation

Comment: If terminate this approach with CMD inside, it creates `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?` [funny effect](https://superuser.com/questions/35698/how-to-supress-terminate-batch-job-y-n-confirmation). It is not so funny for deployment servers. As Start-Process, it is also not a background process and we can't terminate it from a parent process.

Answer (score 4):

Ok so if you need another process entirely but not another file then your best bet is probably .NET runspaces.  Basically wrap your code in a scriptblock

```
$SB = {
  *Your Code*
}
```

Then set up a runspace like below, making sure to use the "UseNewThread" as the thread option.  Note that $arg is whatever your argument to be passed to the script is

```
$newRunspace =[runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$newRunspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
$newRunspace.ThreadOptions = "UseNewThread"         
$newRunspace.Open()
$psCmd = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript($SB).AddArgument($arg)
$psCmd.Runspace = $newRunspace
$data = $psCmd.BeginInvoke()
```

You'll likely need to tweak this if you need to get any data back from the runspace once it is complete but there are a few ways to do that(leave a comment if you need assistance).  If you need synchronous execution rather than async then change `.BeginInvoke()` to `.Invoke()`

Comment: Your solution looks interesting. I my script uses Write-Host "blah blah" So next question is where will the output from Write-Host go now?

Comment: Basically nowhere, but you shouldn't be using write-host outside of development anyway, use Write-Output or return to return your data to the shell.  after that if you use async processing (`.BeginInvoke()`) then you'd do `$results = $psCmd.EndInvoke()` to retrieve the results(which you could then output with `Write-Host` if you really want to) or if you use `.Invoke()` then when the runspace is done it will return your data to do whatever you like with.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the -File parameter and follow it by the path to script. Any unnamed arguments which follows will be passed as script parameters. Something like below should do

```
powershell -File "C:\ScriptFolder\ScriptwithParameters.ps1" "ParameterOneValu" "valuetwo"
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment I forgot to add that I need to run some part of powershell script file in a different process and I cannot use another file.

Comment: It's based on the content. ex: powershell -Command "Get-Process" "excel" will pass the argument "Excel" to cmdlet Get-Process which will inturn get any running excel process. What's your context ? where do u start the powershell from ? Why can't use a script ? (Try and save your command as script to  the temp folder - Worst case)

Answer (score 2):

So should get you started, But it will require a few moving parts.
First we define a new function:

```
function Run-InNewProcess{
  param([String] $code)
  $code = "function Run{ $code }; Run $args"
  $encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String( [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($code))

  start-process PowerShell.exe -argumentlist '-noExit','-encodedCommand',$encoded
}
```

This function will be what starts the new process. It uses the `start-process` cmdlet, The `-Argumentlist` is our arguments applied to the `powershell.exe` You can remove `-noExit` to make the new process close on completion or add other powershell flags, and flags on `Start-Process` to get the windows and behaviours tweaked to your requirements.

Next we define our script block:

```
$script = {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
    [Parameter(Position=0)]
    [string]$Arg1,

    [Parameter(Position=1)]
    [string]$Arg2)

    write-host "I am in another process"
    write-host "Message.Status: $($Arg1) $($Arg2)";
}
```

Here we define some parameters in the opening part of the block, They have a position and name, so for example any argument in position 0 will be in the variable `$arg1` The rest of the code in the block is all executed in the new process.

Now we have defined the script block and the function to run it in a new process, All we have to do is call it:

```
Run-InNewProcess $script -Arg1 '"WHAT WHAT"' -Arg2 '"In the But"'
```

Copy past this code all in to your ISE and you will see it in action.

Answer (score 1):

*Start-Job* will create a process for its scriptblock, and it's straightforward to pass arguments to it.

```
Write-Host "Process count before starting job: $((Get-Process |? { $_.ProcessName -imatch "powershell" }).Count)"

$job = Start-Job `
    -ArgumentList "My argument!" `
    -ScriptBlock { 
        param($arg) 
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5; 
        Write-Host "All Done! Argument: $arg" 
    }

while ($job.State -ne "Completed")
{
    Write-Host "Process count during job: $((Get-Process |? { $_.ProcessName -imatch "powershell" }).Count)"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
Receive-Job $job -AutoRemoveJob -Wait
Write-Host "Process count after job: $((Get-Process |? { $_.ProcessName -imatch "powershell" }).Count)"
```

Comment: Other answers seem overly complicated based just on your request - am I missing something?